# Firebase async upload to Cloud Firestore isn't triggered

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to upload the results of a `Future` to Firebase but I can't seem to figure out how to actually push the objects up.

I have the following method which works as expected however nothing gets uploaded to Firebase, no exceptions are thrown.

```
public void scanDirectory(String directory) {
    final CompletableFuture<Set<Video>> completableFuture = videoService.findFiles();

    completableFuture.thenAccept(results -> {
        log.info("uploading {} files", results.size());

        results.forEach(file -> databaseReference
                .child("files")
                .child(file.getName())
                .setValueAsync(file));
    });
}
```

As there something additional I need to do? I'm working off the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

I am doing this server side using `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.6.0` rather than on a Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scouring more of Googles documentation I found a different page with a different example which works correctly. The trick is I needed to create a `DocumentReference` from the `DatabaseReference` which isn't mentioned in the first documentation I was reading.

Correct method is more like

```
public void scanDirectory(String directory) {
    final CompletableFuture<Set<Video>> completableFuture = videoService.findFiles();

    completableFuture.thenAccept(results -> {
        log.info("uploading {} files", results.size());

        results.forEach(result -> firestore.collection("videos").document().create(result));
    });
}
```

Using docs from: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart